# What's the best and safest way to dynamically create object of derived class passed as default function argument?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, default-arguments

I have a classes

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual string returnString() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
     string returnString() { return "string"; }
}

class C : public A {
public:
     string returnString() { return ""; }
}
```

and function

```
string returnStringFunction(...);
```

I want to be able to pass object of type C but by default, I want this function to use dynamically created object of type B.

I remember using something like this:

```
string returnStringFunction(const A& a = *std::make_unique<B>())
```

or

```
string returnStringFunction(const std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>())
```

Example function body:

```
string returnStringFunction(...) {
    return a->returnString();
}
```

But both of these solutions even though they normally compile and work on my "sandbox" environment, they generate **SIGFAULT** on workspace. Any idea what's causing it or how to better solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Base` → `A`? (...)

Comment: The first gives you a dangling reference. (Please read about the [mcve].)

Comment: "I want to be able to pass object of type C but by default, I want this function to use dynamically created object of type B" - and in your example function has argument of type `std::unique_ptr<A>` with default value being `std::unique_ptr<B>`, where `class A` is not defined. Please be a bit more precise and paste one complete example that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Please paste actual code example that you have actually verified compiles and misbehaves. Don't make something up as you go ... as your problem can't be deciphered from what you write.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are definitely right, first one is really "ugly" way of doing that, even with const reference. Is it really dangling reference though? I thought that lifetime of reference used in function and object dynamically created will be the same since memory should be freed only after nothing uses it anymore.

Comment: @Advent I wouldn't say "definitely" – I'm leaning towards "probably not" myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `const std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>()` should be fine, while the other is not. However, in general default arguments are only second class citizens in C++. If nothing speaks against it I would prefer to overload the function.

If you want the funcion to be callable with and without argument you can provide two overloads:

```
string returnStringFunction(const Base&);
string returnStringFunction() {
     B b;
     returnStringFunction(b);
}
```

Not sure why you would dynamically allocate the `B` here, but if you want you can.

Comment: Deeper dive on default arguments:  those are used at the **callsite**.  For large projects, any changes to default arguments necessitate rebuilding all affected callers.  Using the overloaded function approach instead, changing the *thunk* overload only needs that one file to be rebuilt.

Comment: ...and what could speak agains it is other code excessively using pointers to the function, because that would need to be changed to add a cast. From the top of my head, I am not aware of other reasons

Comment: I agree with both. First solution should work and it can be done with overloading.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest avoiding dynamic memory allocations since there are cheaper ways to do it (unless you have a very strong reason to do it). In this case you can use a const reference:

```cpp
string returnStringFunction(const A& a = B{}) ...
```

Obviously, this limits your function to constant methods, but as far as you have described your problem it should work for you.

If your default object is expensive to construct you can use a singleton or similar as default value:

```cpp
class B : public A {
public:
     string returnString() { return "string"; }

     static B sDefault;
};

// remember to define it somewhere
B B::sDefault;

// ...
string returnStringFunction(const A& a = B::sDefault) ...
```